# Python Reverse Find in String

Tags: python, string, find, reverse

I have a string and an arbitrary index into the string. I want find the first occurrence of a substring before the index.

An example: I want to find the index of the 2nd I by using the index and `str.rfind()`

```
s = "Hello, I am 12! I like plankton but I don't like Baseball."
index = 34 #points to the 't' in 'but'
index_of_2nd_I = s.rfind('I', index)
#returns = 36 and not 16
```

Now I would expect rfind() to return the index of the 2nd I (16) but it returns 36. after looking it up in the docs I found out rfind does not stand for reverse find.

I'm totally new to Python so is there a built in solution to reverse find? Like reversing the string with some python [::-1] magic and using find, etc? Or will I have to reverse iterate char by char through the string?

Comment: If jsz really is 12 then he/she is one bright kid ;-)

Comment: Yep, the start of reverse find is not the rightmost item. I find (on pun intended) the '`r`' in '`rfind`' misleading. It's less ambiguous to see `s.rfind(s,start,end)` as returning the *last* occurrence in `s[start:end]`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your call tell `rfind` to *start looking* at index 34. You want to use the [rfind overload](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) that takes a string, a start and an end. Tell it to start at the beginning of the string (`0`) and stop looking at `index`:

```
>>> s = "Hello, I am 12! I like plankton but I don't like Baseball."
>>> index = 34 #points to the 't' in 'but'
>>> index_of_2nd_I = s.rfind('I', 0, index)
>>>
>>> index_of_2nd_I
16
```

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. It gives the index of the *first* 'I', not what the OP wanted.  To find the 2nd 'I', `s.find('I', s.find('I')+1)` returns 16.  To find the last 'I', `s.rfind('I')` would work.  To find the indeces of all 'I' occurrences: `locs = [idx for idx,ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == 'I']`

Answer (score 2):

I became curious how to implement looking n times for string from end by rpartition and did this nth rpartition loop:

```
orig = s = "Hello, I am 12! I like plankton but I don't like Baseball."
found = tail = ''
nthlast = 2
lookfor = 'I'
for i in range(nthlast):
    tail = found+tail
    s,found,end = s.rpartition(lookfor)
    if not found:
        print "Only %i (less than %i) %r in \n%r" % (i, nthlast, lookfor, orig)
        break
    tail = end + tail
else:
    print(s,found,tail)
```

Comment: Anything specific? The motivation is that unlike the finds the partition has not the start index as it is indexless.

Comment: How is this even relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

To find the 2nd 'I':
`s.find('I', s.find('I')+1) # returns 16`

Find the last 'I':
`s.rfind('I') # returns 36`

Find the indeces of all 'I' occurrences: 
`locs = [idx for idx,ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == 'I'] # [7, 16, 36]`