# how to search backwards in python?

Tags: python, html

I am working with html files which have item 1, item 1a and item 2. is there a way to search backwards and find the item 1a which comes before an item 2?

example:

```
text= """ this is an example item&nbsp;1a thanks for helping item&nbsp;2 blah blah item&nbsp;1a"""
```

Answer (score 5):

Use str.rfind() method to search for the occurence of a string in the reverse direction. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537717/python-reverse-find-in-string) question should also give you some insight on how to go about

Answer (score 0):

yes... use the 'r' functions:

```
text= """ this is an example item&nbsp;1a thanks for helping item&nbsp;2 blah blah item&nbsp;1a"""
text.rfind("1a")
```