# How to search backward several lines in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

There is a solution for searching backward **inline** in [Python Reverse Find in String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537726/3416774):

```
s.rfind('I', 0, index)
```

But if I need to search for a string in several lines above that line? Say I have found the keyword by using:

```
with open("file.txt") as f
    searchlines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "keyword" in line: 
    do_something()
```

I want `do_something()` is to find another keyword backward. To apply the code above, I think I need to `f.read()` so that I can make the file as a string. But this is totally nut, since I have to `readlines()` and `read()` the (large) file. I need to use `readlines()` because the first keyword may appears several times in the text, and I need to find them all.

Is there any better way to do this?

[image: image description]

```
@engineer
- kỹ sư
@engineering
- kỹ thuật
- civil e. ngành xây dựng
- communication e. kỹ thuật thông tin
- control e. kỹ thuật [điều chỉnh, điều khiển] (tự động)
- development e. nghiên cứu những kết cấu mới
```

Comment: could you explain the pic little bit? And it would be nice if those are characters rather than an image.

Comment: Which part you don't understand? Doesn't my question explain the pic already? I don't know if you need the lines from the pic or not. It is there just for illustration. But if you insist...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iL2fT6/1

Comment: This question could be useful: [How to read from a file in python starting from the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568833/how-to-read-lines-from-a-file-in-python-starting-from-the-end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather approach this this way: since you want to find the line starting with `@`, I'd rather store all the lines in a list, then discard the previous lines if a new line that starts with `@` is found.

Thus we get:

```
def do_something(lines):
    print("I've got:")
    print(''.join(lines))

lines = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.startswith('@'):
            lines = []

        lines.append(line)
        if 'development' in line:
            do_something(lines)
```

The output with `file.txt` as you have, will be:

```
I've got:
@engineering
- kỹ thuật
- civil e. ngành xây dựng
- communication e. kỹ thuật thông tin
- control e. kỹ thuật [điều chỉnh, điều khiển] (tự động)
- development e. nghiên cứu những kết cấu mới
```

---

In general case if you want to have just `N` last seen lines, you can use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a list:

```
from collections import deque
N = 100
last_lines = deque(maxlen=N)

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        last_lines.append(line)
        if 'development' in line:
            do_something(last_lines)
```

Now the `do_something` will be passed up to 100 last lines including the current line, if the current line contains the word `development`.

Comment: Simply brilliant. Instead of searching backward, you just remember all the text between two keywords and reset the "memory" if it is not the right one.