# Locate string index then reverse find regex and delete

Tags: python, regex, string, find, reverse

I have similar question as posted previously in [Python Reverse Find in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537717/python-reverse-find-in-string).

Here is a sample of my very long string:

```
t1 = '''1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1281640 city west link rd lilyfield 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1276160 victoria rd rozelle 25/09/2019 14/10/2019 - 15/10/2019 pending 1331626 31/12/2019 - 31/01/2020 incomplete n/a 1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019'''
```

**Update: 1/02/2020**

I am grouping data into lists before putting into a dataframe. I dont want any data associated with `'incomplete n/a'` Do I need to delete string or is there a regex function to recognised `'incomplete n/a'` and group on its position?

I would like two outputs:

**ONE** this list `t1L = ['1281674 ', '1281640 ', '1276160 ']`. Notice this does not include **1331626**.

**TWO** This string to be split or redefined (not containing 1331626) for example:

```
t1 = '''1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1281640 city west link rd lilyfield 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1276160 victoria rd rozelle 25/09/2019 14/10/2019 - 15/10/2019 pending'''
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/0b9Ry9/1) what you want?

Comment: I have updated the post to explain more clearly. How can I stop regex from grouping before reaching `'incomplete n/a'`?

Comment: Please, add the expected output for your example string.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/0b9Ry9/2) what you want?

Comment: In your second output, `1331626` **is** present, but in the text you say you want to remove it. What do you **really** want?

Comment: Sorry removed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is working code for your problem `new_str = t1[:t1.find(re.findall('\d{7}', t1[:t1.find('incomplete n/a')])[-1])])`

Comment: This code generates new string but no list. Any other ideas to get output of list too?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 regexes to get 2 lists:

```
import re

t1 = '''1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1281640 city west link rd lilyfield 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1276160 victoria rd rozelle 25/09/2019 14/10/2019 - 15/10/2019 pending 1331626 31/12/2019 - 31/01/2020 incomplete n/a 1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019'''
clean = re.sub(r'\b\d{7}\b(?=(?:(?!\b\d{7}\b).)*incomplete n/a).*?$', '', t1)
print clean
res = re.findall(r'(\b\d{7}\b)', clean)
print res
```

**Output:**

```
1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1281640 city west link rd lilyfield 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1276160 victoria rd rozelle 25/09/2019 14/10/2019 - 15/10/2019 pending 
['1281674', '1281640', '1276160']
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2FdKjx/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code using loop and conditions.

```
    import re
    t1 = '1281674 the crescent annandale 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1281640 city west link rd lilyfield 02/10/2019 16/10/2019 - 16/11/2019 pending 1276160 victoria rd rozelle 25/09/2019 14/10/2019 - 15/10/2019 pending 1331626 31/12/2019 - 31/01/2020 incomplete n/a 1314832 '

    result = None
    for t in t1.split(" "):

        if re.match("\d{7}",t):
            result = t
        if 'incomplete' in t:
            break

print(result)
```